# Unable to set value onto a reactstrap checkbox using web hook form

Tags: react-hook-form, reactstrap

I have a simple requirement that upon a form being loaded, I want to set the value of a checkbox - but I am unable to do so with defaultValue in useForm or setValue.

This is the snippet of code for the custom input check box component

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="cb-1"
  defaultValue={true}
  render={({ field }) => (
  <CustomInput
    inline type='checkbox' id='cb-1' label='Checkbox'
  />
  )}
/>
```

As above, I even tried setting a default value of true but the checkbox is never checked.

I also tried:

```
<Controller
  as = {<CustomInput inline type='checkbox' id='floodLit' 
    label='Flood Lit?' 
    onChange={ e => { console.log('blah') }}/> }
  control={control}
  name='floodLit'
/>
```

and this too

```
<CustomInput inline type='checkbox' label='Flood Lit?' {...register("floodLit")}/>
```

Nothing works for me !!

I thought that using controller is the right way to register 3rd party components but I am not able to get this work at all, any help would be appreciated. Even a
`setValue('cb-1', true)` 
is not working.
I know I am missing something basic but I am struggling with this and would appreciate any help possible

Ananth